# Is there a way to include a conditional inside of a state declaration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I'm working on a form for a website in React JSX. Depending on the user's type (access level), they will need to be able to see/store different fields in the form. The project I'm working on is one I've just joined (I'm brand new to React) and is too lengthy to share large amounts of code unfortunately. What I'm stuck on is this:

I have some values, let's call them A and B. User 1 shouldn't be able to see A or B, and User 2 needs to see them both. The values are selected from drop down menus, so they need to be able to change (i.e. they need to be 'state' values). However, if I try to add A and B to 'state', I get a console error when I'm User 1 and I access the website, because it's trying to access values that aren't associated with my account/form.

I was hoping I could make some boolean function, let's call it isUser2, which returns true if I'm User 2 and false if I'm not. Then, I could say something like this:

```
this.state = {
  {(this.props.isUser2) &&
    A: // some default value,
    B: // some default value,
  }
  C: // some value that User 1 and User 2 both need to access,
};
```

However, that syntax isn't working, and I just don't know React well enough to understand if something like this is even possible, and why or why not.

As I've said, the project is extensive and is following whatever conventions the previous authors decided on, which are still enforced. The only things I really have to play around with here to make this happen are props and state. If anyone has any insight into this problem I'd appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally insert properties to an object literal.

```
const obj = {
    ...condition && { property: value },
};
```

So, you can do

```
this.state = {
  ...this.props.isUser2 && { A: // some default value },
  ...this.props.isUser2 && { B: // some default value },   
  C: // some value that User 1 and User 2 both need to access,
};
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it conditionally

```js
this.state = {
 ...(true && {
    A: 'some',
    B: 'some',
  }),
  C: 'some',
  ...(false && {E:'E'})
};

console.log(this.state)
```